# How do I map user-defined function in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, user-defined-functions

I'd like to call a user-defined function in Hibernate.

**How (or do I even have to) do I map this in hbm.xml file?**

The function header in MySQL is:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION udfUSDtoPLN(kwota DECIMAL(18,2), kurs DECIMAL(18,2))
RETURNS decimal(18,2)
```

I tried in hmb.xml:

```xml
<sql-query name="udfUSDtoPLN" callable="true">
    <return-scalar column="kwota" type="big_decimal" />
    { ? = call udfUSDtoPLN(?, ?) }
</sql-query>
```

Then I want to use this function in code like:

```java
    String queryString1 = "SELECT p.idPlatnosc, p.kwota, udfUSDtoPLN(1, 2)"
            + " FROM Tplatnosc AS p";
    Query query1 = session.createQuery(queryString1);
```

And it throws the below exception at query1 line:

```
No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode
```

Same is thrown when I name the function "blah" in the queryString1, so I guess it just doesn't find it wherever it's looking for it.